# Translate variables from a Textfile

Tags: python

Let's say I have a textfile which is built like this:

```
text "car"
translation ""

text "tree"
translation ""
```

Now I'm trying to translate this file with Python and I have figured out how to translate strings with googletrans and how to read a file but I can't figure out how to actually read what's within the quotation marks only.

This is how far I have gotten

```
from googletrans import Translator
f = open('file.txt','r')
translator = Translator()
text=f.read()
```

Comment: `line.split('"')[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get just the values inside the quotes by using the very helpful [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) module, which provides utilities for parsing shell-like syntaxes:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('text "car"')
['text', 'car']
```

Note that in addition to stripping the quotation marks, this supports spaces, and escaped quotes, etc:

```
>>> shlex.split(r'text "a thing with spaces and literal \"s in it"')
['text', 'a thing with spaces and literal "s in it']
```

You can hook this up to your file with something like:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file_:
    for line in file_:
        parsed = shlex.split(line)
        if parsed[0] == "text":
             # do translation with with parsed[1]
        else:
             # do something else
```